# Convert to epoch in python

Tags: python

I have got a time in this format 2019-05-01T01:59 and I need to convert it into epoch.

```
 pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
 datefromsec = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(datefrom, pattern)))
```

I am trying with this code but I am getting this error
time data u'2019-05-01T01:59' does not match format.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M` add `T` character.

Comment: Didnt notice it. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong - you are missing the **T**

Solution:

```
pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
```

Comment: could have been a comment, just saying

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern was incorrect. It should have been `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M` instead of `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`.
You can then calculate epoch as follows .

```
import datetime

pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
s = '2019-05-01T01:59'

dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(s,pattern)

#Get epoch date
epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

#Print epoch
print((dt_obj - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0)
```

The output will be `1556675940000.0`